Installing Tensorflow (building pip package)
I'm tring to install tensorflow 2.6.0 on WSL2. I follow the guide (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source?hl=pl) and after:
bazel build //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:wheel --repo_env=WHEEL_NAME=tensorflow --config=cuda

I have an error:
Auto-Configuration Warning: 'TMP' environment variable is not set, using 'C:\Windows\Temp' as default
ERROR: Skipping '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:wheel': no such target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:wheel': target 'wheel' not declared in package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package' defined by /home/jakmacc/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: no such target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:wheel': target 'wheel' not declared in package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package' defined by /home/jakmacc/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD
INFO: Elapsed time: 10.827s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (2 packages loaded)

I don't know how to solve it.
I want to solve that mistake.
I tried also that command:
bazel build //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:wheel --repo_env=WHEEL_NAME=tensorflow_cpu


replace "//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:wheel" to "//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package" and try again

Solved my issue when compiling TF v2.8. Thanks.
